# You are loading the CommonJS build of React Router on a page that is already running the ES modules build, so things won't work right

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Error: You are loading the CommonJS build of React Router on a page that is already running the ES modules build, so things won't work right.

```js
//App.js

import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import LandingPage from "../src/pages/LandingPage";
import MainPage from "../src/pages/MainPage";
import Question from "../src/components/QuestionIcon";
import RichRoadLogo from "../src/img/richroad.png";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <Logo src={RichRoadLogo} />
          <Profile />
        </Head>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Body>
              <LandingPage />
            </Body>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/main">
            <Body>
              <MainPage />
            </Body>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Question />
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```js
//LandingPage.js

import React from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";
import google from "../img/google.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; //This is the problem.

function LandingPage() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>
        나의 투자 수익률을
        <br />
        기록해보세요
      </Text>

      <LoginButton src={google} />
      <Link to="main">
        <GuestButton>구경하기</GuestButton>
      </Link>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

If you write `import { Link } from "react-router-dom"` from LandingPage.js, you get an error. Please, I need your help.

"react-router-dom" version is ^5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem surrounding the `<Body>` tag. I wrote it as below and it was solved.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <Logo src={RichRoadLogo} />
        </Head>
        <Switch>
          <Body>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <LandingPage />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/main">
              <Profile />
              <MainPage />
            </Route>
          </Body>
        </Switch>
        <Question />
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and

```js
<Link to="main"> //a typing error
<Link to="/main"> // solved
```

Comment: What did the Body component have in it that made this change work? If <Body /> is just a div or something, how is that any different from <LandingPage /> or <Profile />?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you use multiple types of imports from the `react-router`:

```js
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Link from "react-router-dom/Link";
```

this solved it for me:

```
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while running the unit test cases for a react component. The component made use of the `useLocation()` hook provided by `react-router-dom`. All I did to resolve this was mock the module in my test file like this,

```
  jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useLocation: () => { 
      //return stuffs the you want to use
      search: ''
      pathname: ''
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error `You are loading the CommonJS build of React Router on a page that is already running the ES modules build,` you can mock the `react-router-dom` module to ensure consistency in module loading across your application.

You can achieve this by using Jest's `jest.mock` functionality.

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useHistory: () => ({
        push: jest.fn(),
    }),
}));
```

This code snippet mocks the `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom`, providing a mock implementation where the `push` function is replaced with a Jest mock function.

By doing this, you ensure that even if there are inconsistencies in how React Router is imported or loaded in different parts of your application, the `useHistory` hook will have a consistent behavior, mitigating the error.

This approach helps in maintaining compatibility and consistency, ensuring smooth functioning of your React Router-dependent components across different parts of your application.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a conflict of running two different build modules.

1. Go to node_modules folder and look for the react-router-dom
2. Expand the folder and what I did is that I removed the es folder because it contained similar js files which was in the same folder of react-router-dom.

es folder was here which made the conflict:
[es folder was here which made the conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEvI9.png)

Comment: Sorry, gonna down vote. Removing anything from node_modules isn't a long term solution. Once you install/build again, the files will return so this only works as long as you don't install again and/or commit node_modules and/or you constantly remember to do this after each install.